# How to fix gradient color on SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, gradient

I am a beginner and I am trying to use gradient color on SVG. But the color is not matching with the previous div.

I have used gradient color on `.test` and the color is:

```
background: linear-gradient(
    60deg,
    rgba(84, 58, 183, 1) 0%,
    rgba(0, 172, 193, 1) 100%
  );
```

I have used SVG on `.test-2` div. I want it seems like there is no partition between the two divs.

Here is an image:

[image]

My Codes:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.test {
  background: linear-gradient(
    60deg,
    rgba(84, 58, 183, 1) 0%,
    rgba(0, 172, 193, 1) 100%
  );
  width: 100%;
  height: 65vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>Demo Text</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat aspernatur nemo accusantium soluta quidem cum obcaecati amet, deserunt, quo cupiditate quam vel excepturi quas laboriosam consequuntur sapiente! Necessitatibus, nesciunt quae non, optio cumque assumenda commodi minima qui quo animi a! Laudantium inventore vero est sunt. Facere incidunt quisquam debitis ipsa maiores totam excepturi nesciunt perferendis repudiandae eum. Esse tenetur nemo asperiores nihil autem dolor atque molestias amet quaerat consequatur? Iste delectus culpa atque voluptates debitis voluptatem fuga, ab mollitia earum quibusdam ipsum numquam soluta, quia molestiae animi nisi obcaecati rem aliquid amet? Quam beatae sunt ad dolores numquam magni ratione!</p>
</div>

<div class="test-2">
  <svg id="wave" style="transform:rotate(180deg); transition: 0.3s" viewBox="0 0 1440 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient id="sw-gradient-0" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0" gradientTransform="rotate(60)"><stop stop-color="rgba(84, 58, 183, 1)" offset="0%"></stop><stop stop-color="rgba(0, 172, 193, 1)" offset="100%"></stop></linearGradient></defs><path style="transform:translate(0, 0px); opacity:1" fill="url(#sw-gradient-0)" d="M0,30L80,65C160,100,320,170,480,200C640,230,800,220,960,180C1120,140,1280,70,1440,80C1600,90,1760,180,1920,205C2080,230,2240,190,2400,165C2560,140,2720,130,2880,105C3040,80,3200,40,3360,55C3520,70,3680,140,3840,170C4000,200,4160,190,4320,180C4480,170,4640,160,4800,150C4960,140,5120,130,5280,115C5440,100,5600,80,5760,85C5920,90,6080,120,6240,140C6400,160,6560,170,6720,145C6880,120,7040,60,7200,70C7360,80,7520,160,7680,200C7840,240,8000,240,8160,215C8320,190,8480,140,8640,105C8800,70,8960,50,9120,65C9280,80,9440,130,9600,130C9760,130,9920,80,10080,70C10240,60,10400,90,10560,100C10720,110,10880,100,11040,115C11200,130,11360,170,11440,190L11520,210L11520,300L11440,300C11360,300,11200,300,11040,300C10880,300,10720,300,10560,300C10400,300,10240,300,10080,300C9920,300,9760,300,9600,300C9440,300,9280,300,9120,300C8960,300,8800,300,8640,300C8480,300,8320,300,8160,300C8000,300,7840,300,7680,300C7520,300,7360,300,7200,300C7040,300,6880,300,6720,300C6560,300,6400,300,6240,300C6080,300,5920,300,5760,300C5600,300,5440,300,5280,300C5120,300,4960,300,4800,300C4640,300,4480,300,4320,300C4160,300,4000,300,3840,300C3680,300,3520,300,3360,300C3200,300,3040,300,2880,300C2720,300,2560,300,2400,300C2240,300,2080,300,1920,300C1760,300,1600,300,1440,300C1280,300,1120,300,960,300C800,300,640,300,480,300C320,300,160,300,80,300L0,300Z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

*[Please run the snippet in full screen]*

Comment: If you put the linear gradient background on a container which is the height you want (or just make .test taller) you can then use a CSS clip-path to create the wave effect rather than trying to tack on an svg at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You must merg both parts.
You can do this through Adobe Illustrator or online tools such as https://editor.method.ac/. and export as svg file.
then use svg file as background image.

Answer (score 0):

I got it very close to perfect for you:

```
<div class="test">
  <h1>Demo Text</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat aspernatur nemo accusantium soluta quidem cum obcaecati amet, deserunt, quo cupiditate quam vel excepturi quas laboriosam consequuntur sapiente! Necessitatibus, nesciunt quae non, optio cumque assumenda commodi minima qui quo animi a! Laudantium inventore vero est sunt. Facere incidunt quisquam debitis ipsa maiores totam excepturi nesciunt perferendis repudiandae eum. Esse tenetur nemo asperiores nihil autem dolor atque molestias amet quaerat consequatur? Iste delectus culpa atque voluptates debitis voluptatem fuga, ab mollitia earum quibusdam ipsum numquam soluta, quia molestiae animi nisi obcaecati rem aliquid amet? Quam beatae sunt ad dolores numquam magni ratione!</p>
</div>
<div class="test-2">
  <svg id="wave" style="transform:rotate(180deg); transition: 0.3s" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1440 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient id="sw-gradient-0" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"><stop stop-color="rgba(0, 172, 193, 1)" offset="0%"></stop><stop stop-color="rgba(84, 58, 183, 1)" offset="10%"></stop></linearGradient></defs><path style="opacity:1" fill="url(#sw-gradient-0)" d="M0,30L80,65C160,100,320,170,480,200C640,230,800,220,960,180C1120,140,1280,70,1440,80C1600,90,1760,180,1920,205C2080,230,2240,190,2400,165C2560,140,2720,130,2880,105C3040,80,3200,40,3360,55C3520,70,3680,140,3840,170C4000,200,4160,190,4320,180C4480,170,4640,160,4800,150C4960,140,5120,130,5280,115C5440,100,5600,80,5760,85C5920,90,6080,120,6240,140C6400,160,6560,170,6720,145C6880,120,7040,60,7200,70C7360,80,7520,160,7680,200C7840,240,8000,240,8160,215C8320,190,8480,140,8640,105C8800,70,8960,50,9120,65C9280,80,9440,130,9600,130C9760,130,9920,80,10080,70C10240,60,10400,90,10560,100C10720,110,10880,100,11040,115C11200,130,11360,170,11440,190L11520,210L11520,300L11440,300C11360,300,11200,300,11040,300C10880,300,10720,300,10560,300C10400,300,10240,300,10080,300C9920,300,9760,300,9600,300C9440,300,9280,300,9120,300C8960,300,8800,300,8640,300C8480,300,8320,300,8160,300C8000,300,7840,300,7680,300C7520,300,7360,300,7200,300C7040,300,6880,300,6720,300C6560,300,6400,300,6240,300C6080,300,5920,300,5760,300C5600,300,5440,300,5280,300C5120,300,4960,300,4800,300C4640,300,4480,300,4320,300C4160,300,4000,300,3840,300C3680,300,3520,300,3360,300C3200,300,3040,300,2880,300C2720,300,2560,300,2400,300C2240,300,2080,300,1920,300C1760,300,1600,300,1440,300C1280,300,1120,300,960,300C800,300,640,300,480,300C320,300,160,300,80,300L0,300Z"></path>    </svg>
</div>
```

and

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.test {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg,rgba(84, 58, 183, 1) 19%,rgba(0, 172, 193, 1) 88%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 65vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctbh2ex1/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not fully responsive - try it on a long narrow viewport - the svg 'starts again' with the linear gradient so cannot be continuous with the text div's background.

Comment: @AHaworth - darn, you're correct. Ultimately, I think using an SVG to achieve this wave effect is a bad way to accomplish this. I would rather create a PNG image and add that below the div than attempt to make this work. Even doing a CSS clip-path is going to be a lot harder to manage than slapping an image down there that you can quickly Photoshop (or do in MS paint, GIMP, etc.).

Comment: The problem with using images is responsivenss - yes they can scale but you need a high def one to cover all possible device sizes.